# Updates made via admin to m2m Django field are not persisted in the database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many

I`m new to Django and completely stuck with this one. This pet project is a website for online school. The default flow would be: user signups and has the role Student by default, then if this user is a school teacher admin updates the role to Teacher.

I have the following User model which has role field, I plan to use it to display correct content for the user on the website, since I dont want to use groups and permissions for this purpose, at least not yet. But I want to have groups in sync with User roles and use groups to manage permissions inside admin.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name="email address")
    first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=150)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(_("last updated to user"), auto_now=True)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=UserRolesChoices.choices, default=UserRolesChoices.STUDENT
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateTimeField(_("date of birth"), null=True, blank=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(_("profile picture"), null=True, blank=True,
                                        upload_to=profile_pic_directory_path,
                                        storage=OverwriteStorage)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return (self.role in (UserRoles.TEACHER, UserRoles.ADMIN)) or self.is_superuser

    @property
    def is_teacher(self):
        return self.role == UserRoles.TEACHER


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_new_user = not self.pk
        changed_fields = set()
        if not is_new_user:
            # If self.pk is not None then it's an update.
            cls = self.__class__
            old = cls.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            # This will get the current model state since super().save() isn't called yet.
            new = self  # This gets the newly instantiated Mode object with the new values.
            for field in cls._meta.get_fields():
                field_name = field.name
                try:
                    print(field_name, getattr(old, field_name), getattr(new, field_name))
                    if getattr(old, field_name) != getattr(new, field_name):
                        changed_fields.add(field_name)
                except Exception as ex:  # Catch field does not exist exception
                    pass

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        print('is_new_user', is_new_user)
        print('changed_fields', changed_fields)
        if is_new_user:
            update_user_group(user=self)
        else:
            if 'role' in changed_fields:
                update_user_group(user=self)
```

I have updated the `save` method to check if its a new user and if yes, then to assign user to appropriate group. If its an existing user, then I check if the role field was updated and then update the group assosiation. Below is the code for `update_user_group`.

```
def update_user_group(user):
    group_name = ROLES_TO_GROUPS_MAPPING.get(user.role)
    print(f'{user} group name {group_name}')
    if group_name:
        group, group_created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=group_name)
        print(f'got group {group}, created {group_created}')
        print(f'user.groups.all {user.groups.all()}')
        # group.user_set.add(user)
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(
                "SELECT * FROM accounts_user_groups WHERE user_id = %s AND group_id = %s LIMIT 1",
                [user.id, group.id],
            )
            row_exists = cursor.fetchone()
            print(user.id, group.id, 'row_exists', row_exists)
            if not row_exists:
                # Insert the user-group association if it doesn't exist
                cursor.execute(
                    "INSERT INTO accounts_user_groups (user_id, group_id) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                    [user.id, group.id],
                )
                print(cursor.fetchone())

        print(f'after user.groups.all {user.groups.all()}')
```

I tried raw SQL out of despair, because ORM failed, but in the end result is the same.
When I create user via website (not admin) everything works as expected, the group assosiation is created and user falls into Students group [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcWp2.png)
But when I create user through admin, in the console I see that the assoisiation with group is created, but in reality these changes are not persisted in db therefor there is no assosiation with group. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxC9w.png)

FYI: I just registered this User model in admin, haven`t added any customization yet.

When I update the role in admin, the changes are also not persisted in db. [updating test1 user in admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFcIi.png)[debug output after user role update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2NTM.png)

I have initially used post_save signal for group assosiation, but faced that issue and tried in save method, but no result as you see.

**UPDATE:**
Looks like the issue was that in admin form had both the groups field and role field, so even if I didn`t touch the groups field because if conflicted with my programmatic group association logic my changes were discarded. So when I updated admin and removed the groups field everything seemed to work as expected. But what if I wanted to have the ability to manage user groups via admin, any ideas how would be possible to overcome this?